# How to add tr on click using angularJS

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, django

Hi my goal is to create a new tr in my table once the user clicks the add button. The following is my html & angularcode:

HTML:

```
<tr>
                    <td contenteditable='true' ng-model="item"></td>
                    <td>
                        {%verbatim%}
                        <select ng-model="s_value" class="form-control">
                          <option value="">--Select--</option>
                          <option ng-repeat="s in sev_list">
                            {{ s.rank}}-{{s.specific_value }}</option>
                        </select>
                        {%endverbatim%}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {%verbatim%}
                            <select ng-model="o_value" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                <option ng-repeat="o in occ_list" ng-value="s.rank" >{{o.rank}}-{{o.specific_value}}</option>
                         {%endverbatim%}
                            </select>
                    </td>
                    <td contenteditable='true' ng-model="control"></td>
                    <td>
                        {%verbatim%}
                            <select ng-model="d_value" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                <option ng-repeat="d in det_list" ng-value="s.rank" >{{d.rank}}-{{d.specific_value}}</option>
                         {%endverbatim%}
                            </select>
                    </td>
                    <td style="background-color: yellow;" ng-model="rpn"></td>
                    <td contenteditable='true' ng-model="r_action"></td>
                    <td>
                        {%verbatim%}
                        <select ng-model="s_new" class="form-control">
                          <option value="">--Select--</option>
                          <option ng-repeat="s in sev_list">
                            {{ s.rank}}-{{s.specific_value }}</option>
                        </select>
                        {%endverbatim%}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {%verbatim%}
                            <select ng-model="o_new" class="form-control">
                                <<option value="">--Select--</option>
                                <option ng-repeat="o in occ_list" ng-value="s.rank" >{{o.rank}}-{{o.specific_value}}</option>
                         {%endverbatim%}
                            </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {%verbatim%}
                            <select ng-model="d_new" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                <option ng-repeat="d in det_list" ng-value="s.rank" >{{d.rank}}-{{d.specific_value}}</option>
                         {%endverbatim%}
                            </select>
                    </td>
                    <td style="background-color: yellow;" ng-model="rpn_new"></td>
                    <td width="1px" style="border-style: hidden;">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button><br/><br/>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

ANGULAR:

```
$scope.addFm = function() {
            $scope.fm = {};
            $scope.final_data.checks.push($scope.fm);
        };


        $scope.final_data = {user:$scope.user};

        $scope.submit = function () {
            data = {};
            angular.extend(data, $scope.final_data);
            angular.extend(data, { fms : $scope.final_data.fms });
            $http.post('{% url 'createfm_submit'  %}', data).success(function(data){
                $modalInstance.close();
            }).error(function(){
                alert('Internal Error Need Developer Attention.');
            });
        };
```

The structure might be a list inside the dictionary? I mean each item will create a list in the dictionary and we ng-repeat (k,v) from dictionary in tr? Bit confused. Can someone give me a solution? Am bit new to angularJS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you indent your code?

Comment: @vellattukudy is your <tr> wrapping in ng-repeat? so your question is, when ever user click the + icon button, then the same <tr> that you show us above will be populate in the next row. am I right?

Comment: Make it difficult on yourself using server side templating instead of angular templating. Is so simple to push an object to a data array to create new row using `ng-repeat`. Then angular will manage the dom for you as it is designed to do

Comment: Yeah, a new empty tr will will be added on clicking the plus button mtamma

Comment: Can show me an example Charlietfi

Comment: `<tr ng-repeat="item in items">` then in controller when you get a new item simply push it to `$scope.items.push(newItem)`. Angular will observe the data change and update dom automatically

Comment: Charlietfi, its a list of items actually